# dotnetopenauth versus WIF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dotnetopenauth, wif

I need to add social media login capabilities to a site and got stuck a bit, mostly because of the, more or less, non existing beginner documentation regarding these two.

I grasped the basics of DotNetOpenAuth by checking nerddinner but some here suggest WIF so I started looking into it. I realized quickly that just getting clear info explaining if this is feasible at all on shared hosting was not easy. I don't really want to pump through all reference knowledge, technical overviews (checked some out anyway), but just to be able to see the basic functionality.

So my questions are:

1. Where can I find any tutorials showing the basics and bare minimums needed for WIF to function in an explanatory manner? Preferably setting up WIF in a single MVC site combined with local authorization. Is there any step-by-step documentation at all?
2. Is WIF feasible, at all, on a single site or would the best option be to find other solutions like DotNetOpenAuth or use the separate APIs? When trying to get to the bottom of this, I have only found information regarding the value of WIF in large, multi-application, and platform environments combined with AD / ADFSv2. Which is completely outisde the bounds of what I need.
3. When I look at information on WIF, it's mostly linked to ADFSv2 and STS. Is this possible to implement at all for deployment on shared hosting for example?

Any input on the matter is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

WIF - see the How-to section [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/3665.aspx).

Also [Get Started with Windows Identity Foundation (WIF)](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/3487.aspx).

Your best bet is probably to use WIF / ACS. Good link [here](http://www.syfuhs.net/post/2011/04/21/Windows-Azure-Access-Control-Services-Federation-with-Facebook.aspx) or look at [Windows Identity Foundation (WIF) and Azure AppFabric Access Control Service (ACS) Content Map](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1546.aspx).

The other way is to add OAuth2 to a custom STS. Refer [Identity Server](http://identityserver.codeplex.com/) for a really good example of this.

Answer (score 0):

DotNetOpenAuth definitely works on shared hosting, and requires *no* set up on the web server at all (it's just a .dll in your web site's Bin folder).  Depending on the social networking sites in particular that you want to hook up to, it can be just a few lines of code to wire everything up if you're hooking up to OpenID enabled sites.

If the sites you're hooking to use OAuth or OAuth 2, there is more code to write for each individual site to work against their particular proprietary API, but that would also be true for WIF unless they have code to support specific web sites that happen to align with your own.